# Java - Mock private static constructor for multiple tests

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito, easymock

I'm new to java testing and have been fiddling with this for a bit now with no luck, I have the following classes:

```
public class Bar {
    public Object doSomething(int a, String b){
        return "something";
    }

    public Object doSomethingElse(int a, int b, String c){
        return "something else";
    }
}
```

```
public class Foo {
    private static Bar bar = new Bar();

    public static void start(int a, int b, String c){
        if(a == 1) { // some calculated condition
            bar.doSomething(a, c);
        } else {
            bar.doSomethingElse(a, b, c);
        }
    }
}
```

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Foo.class)
public class FooTest {
    @Test
    public void somethingTest() throws Exception {
        Bar barMock = createMock(Bar.class);

        expectNew(Bar.class).andReturn(barMock);

        expect(barMock.doSomething(1, "xxx")).andReturn("ABC");

        replay(barMock, Bar.class);

        Foo.start(1, 2, "xxx");
        verify(barMock, Bar.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void somethingElseTest() throws Exception {
        Bar barMock = createMock(Bar.class);

        expectNew(Bar.class).andReturn(barMock);

        expect(barMock.doSomethingElse(0, 2,"xxx")).andReturn("ABC");

        replay(barMock, Bar.class);

        Foo.start(0, 2, "xxx");
        verify(barMock, Bar.class);
    }
}
```

Running tests individually work, but not the entire class, I think it has to do with the:

```
 private static Bar bar = new Bar();
```

but I'm not 100% sure. Either way, assuming I can't change the foo / bar classes, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Private static constructor?

Comment: I realize this is not great, I'm just trying to figure out how something like this COULD be tested.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor Foo as:

```
public class Foo {
    private static Bar bar = new Bar();

    public static void start(int a, int b, String c){
        if(a == 1) { // some calculated condition
            doSomething(a, c);
        } else {
            doSomethingElse(a, b, c);
        }
    }

    private static void doSomething(int a, String c) {
        bar.doSomething(a, c);
    }

    private static void doSomethingElse(int a, int b, String c) {
        bar.doSomethingElse(a, b, c);
    }
}
```

And test Foo like:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.eq;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;


@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Foo.class})
public class FooTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.spy(Foo.class);
    }


    @Test
    public void somethingTest() throws Exception {
        Foo.start(1, 2, "xxx");   
        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(Foo.class).invoke("doSomething", eq(1), eq("xxx"));
    }

    @Test
    public void somethingElseTest() throws Exception {
        Foo.start(0, 2, "xxx"); 
        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(Foo.class).invoke("doSomethingElse", AdditionalMatchers.not(eq(1)), eq(2), eq("xxx"));
    }
}
```

And test Bar separately, which can be done simply with Mockito.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that a `static` field of a `class` is only initialized once. Hence the first test creates a new `Bar` object, but this mock persists through all other tests as no new creation is triggered.

Instead you should use `Reflections` to set the `private static` field for each test. `PowerMock` provides you a utility class called `Whitebox`.

Also note that the `setInternalState` only works if there is exactly one instance of a `Bar` object in that class. You would need to rely on the normal Java Reflection classes if there would be multiple.

Example see below:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("test.Foo") // optional, only required if the Bar class could not be created normally.
public class StaticTest {

    @Test
    public void somethingTest() throws Exception {
        Bar barMock = createMock(Bar.class);
        Whitebox.setInternalState(Foo.class, barMock);

        expect(barMock.doSomething(1, "xxx")).andReturn("ABC");

        replay(barMock, Bar.class);

        Foo.start(1, 2, "xxx");
        verify(barMock, Bar.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void somethingElseTest() throws Exception {
        Bar barMock = createMock(Bar.class);
        Whitebox.setInternalState(Foo.class, barMock);

        expect(barMock.doSomethingElse(0, 2,"xxx")).andReturn("ABC");

        replay(barMock, Bar.class);

        Foo.start(0, 2, "xxx");
        verify(barMock, Bar.class);
    }
}
```

I combined this with the suppresion of the static initialisation, but strictly speaking that is not necessary for your test, as the creation of the `Bar` class succeeds regardless.

The annotation should only be used in case the `Bar` class can not be created.
Note that you would need to enter the fully quallified name including the package name there (I assumed the package would be `test`).